# How can i search inside JSON array object PHP with search box

Tags: php, json

I made a search box, and i want to search inside JSON data which i take it from this url: https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/

This is the code how i recive tha data :

```
<?php

  $url = 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/';

  $cURL = curl_init();

  curl_setopt($cURL, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
  curl_setopt($cURL, CURLOPT_HTTPGET, true);
  curl_setopt($cURL, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

  curl_setopt($cURL, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
      'Content-Type: application/json',
      'Accept: application/json'
  ));

  $result = curl_exec($cURL);

  curl_close($cURL);

  $arrays =  json_decode($result);

 ?>
```

And this is the HTML code for search box and button:

```
<form action="search.php" method="POST" style="search-style";>
      <input type="text" name="search" placeholder="Search" >
      <button type="submit" name="submit-search">Search</button>
</form>
```

And this is the PHP code for SEARCH but i dont know how to finis it :

```
<div>
  <?php
    if (isset($_POST['submit-search'])) {
      $search = $????? ($_POST['search']);  // i dont know how it works, i need a variable 

      foreach ($arrays as $key => $value) {
        echo $value -> $search ;
      }
    }
       ?>
</div>
```

At the end i need to show the result in table or something like that. But i can't get the result..
Any suggestion? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Are you getting right data according your search ??

Comment: i'm getting 1 array inside with 200 objects. And i want to search inside that objects. But i don't know how.

Comment: What have you tried so far? If there are 200 objects in the JSON array, why not loop over them and compare whatever you want to compare?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have an array of objects so just search for part or all of the string in I assume `title`:

```
if(isset($_POST['submit-search']) && !empty($_POST['search'])) {
  foreach($arrays as $value) {
      //find partial match
      if(strpos($value->title, $_POST['search']) !== false) {
          echo $value->title . '<br />';
      }
  }
}
```

For a full match:

```
if($value->title == $_POST['search']) {
```

Answer (score 0):

you send your request to `search.php` actually you redirect to search.php.

for use this code in one page you must put `search.php` code in main file.

you recive data when open site.
and in search form you send a key(string-title-id...anything) and in last part you filter it
your final code must be like this

```
<?php
$url = 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/';
$cURL = curl_init();
curl_setopt($cURL, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($cURL, CURLOPT_HTTPGET, true);
curl_setopt($cURL, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($cURL, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
    'Content-Type: application/json',
    'Accept: application/json'
));
$result = curl_exec($cURL);
curl_close($cURL);
$arrays =  json_decode($result);
?>
<form action="#" method="POST" style="search-style";>
    <input type="text" name="Title" placeholder="Enter Title..." >
    <button type="submit" name="submit_search">Search</button>
</form>

<div>
    <?php
    if(isset($_POST['submit_search']) && !empty($_POST['Title'])) {
        $Title = $_POST['Title'];
        foreach($arrays as $value) {
            if(strpos($value->title, $Title) !== false) {
                echo "Title : ";
                echo $value->title ."<br/>";
                echo "Id : " ;
                echo $value->id ."<br/>";
            }
        }
    }
    ?>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I do it like this and it worked. Thanks!

```
    <?php include 'header.php';

  if(isset($_POST['submit-search']) && !empty($_POST['search'])) {
//  $search = $_POST['search']; ?>
<table >
      <p style=" text-align:center; font-size:100%";>Resulti from search :</p>
      <tr>
        <th>User ID:</th>
          <th>ID:</th>
          <th>Title:</th>
          <th>Compiled:</th>
      </tr>
<?php  foreach ($arrays as $value) {
      if(strpos($value->title, $_POST['search']) !== false) {?>
        <tr>
          <td><?php echo $value ->userId ?> </td>
          <td><?php echo $value ->id ?> </td>
          <td> <?php echo $value->title ?> </td>
          <td><?php echo $value ->completed ?> </td>
        </tr>
      <?php //  echo $value->title . '</br>'; ?>

<?php   }
      }
    }
   ?>
</table>
```